# Enumerating binary trees in Prolog

Tags: prolog, logic-programming, catalan, instantiation-error

I am trying to create Prolog rules to enumerate 'binary trees' in list form in Prolog. I am new to Prolog.

A tree with 0 nodes is an empty list:

```
[]
```

A tree with 1 node is:

```
[[],[]]
```

A tree with 2 nodes has 2 possibilities:

```
[[],[[],[]]]

[[[],[]],[]]
```

and so on.

Here are my rules:

```
bintree(0,[]).
bintree(1,[[],[]]).
bintree(N,[Lc,Rc]) :-
  N > 1,
  bintree(N1,Lc),
  bintree(N2,Rc),
  N1 >= 0,
  N2 >= 0,
  N3 is N1+N2+1,
  N==N3.
```

Queries for 0 and 1 obviously work. For N=2, it prints one of the possibilities, but gives an error after I input the semicolon to get the other possibility.
Queries for N>2 directly give an error. The error is always the same:

```
ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I read about this error on some websites, but I can't figure out what is causing this error here.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: No, that makes it go into an infinite loop.

Comment: To use an expression comparator in Prolog, all expressions must be fully instantiated (values known). You got the error because `N` had no value when you tried `N > 1`. What kind of query are you trying to satisfy? It's not at all clear in your question.

Comment: It expects a pair. The first is a positive integer which is the number of nodes in the tree. The second is a tree in the format given that has that many number of nodes. Ex. bintree(2,A). should give A=[[],[[],[]]] ; A=[[[],[]],[]] which is the representation of the two binary trees with 2 nodes. It should terminate for all positive integers given as the first argument.

Comment: In your clause, the expressions `bintree(N1, Lc)` and `bintree(N2, Rc)` are being called with `N1` and `N2` uninstantiated variables. So the subsequenet `N > 1` will fail on that error message.

Comment: I am trying to satisfy the type of query such as bintree(5,X). This will make prolog print the representation of a binary tree with 5 nodes. Each empty list [] is like a NULL pointer in C. A list with 2 elements [L,R] is a node which has the two elements L and R as children. When prompted with the semicolon, prolog should print all the possible trees for X having that many number of nodes, then print false.

Comment: @lurker Ok, I changed the order to the following: `bintree(N,[Cl,Cr]) :- integer(Nl), integer(Nr), Nl>=0, Nr>=0, Ns is Nl+Nr+1, N==Ns, bintree(Nl,Cl), bintree(Nr,Cr).` Now, I get false for all N>1. Basically I want it to try constructing left and right subtrees such that the sum of nodes in them, plus 1 (their parent) is equal to N.

Comment: English definition of my rules:
Binary tree with 0 nodes: empty list. Empty list represents NULL pointer.
Binary tree with 1 node : list containing 2 empty lists. Represents node with 2 NULL pointers as its children.
[Cl,Cr] is a binary tree with N nodes if there exist non -ve integers Nl and Nr such that Nl+Nr+1=N and Cl is a binary tree with Nl nodes and Cr is a binary tree with Nr nodes.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14096747/772868)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the CLPFD library will help give a clean solution to generating the sizes. Then you don't need a wonky (;)) `integer/1` predicate, which can be problematic:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

bintree(0,[]).
bintree(1,[[],[]]).
bintree(N, [L, R]) :-
    N #> 1,
    N #= N1 + N2 + 1,
    N1 #>= 0, N2 #>= 0,
    bintree(N1, L), bintree(N2, R).
```

Or simpler (thanks to @repeat's suggestion):

```
bintree(0,[]).
bintree(N, [L, R]) :-
    N #> 0,
    N #= N1 + N2 + 1,
    N1 #>= 0, N2 #>= 0,
    bintree(N1, L), bintree(N2, R).

?- bintree(4, L).
L = [[], [[], [[], [[], []]]]] ;
L = [[], [[], [[[], []], []]]] ;
L = [[], [[[], []], [[], []]]] ;
L = [[], [[[], [[], []]], []]] ;
L = [[], [[[[], []], []], []]] ;
L = [[[], []], [[], [[], []]]] ;
L = [[[], []], [[[], []], []]] ;
L = [[[], [[], []]], [[], []]] ;
L = [[[], [[], [[], []]]], []] ;
L = [[[], [[[], []], []]], []] ;
L = [[[[], []], []], [[], []]] ;
L = [[[[], []], [[], []]], []] ;
L = [[[[], [[], []]], []], []] ;
L = [[[[[], []], []], []], []] ;
false.

?-
```

CLPFD is a nice, declarative way of expressing numeric constraints.

Comment: Thanks. Is this possible using only pure prolog, without this library?

Comment: This library *is* pure. Try for example GNU Prolog or B Prolog, where you do not have to import any library to use such an elementary feature as finite domain constraints. Great solution, +1!

Answer (score 0):

I know I posted this question a year ago, but I managed to solve it later without using any libraries. Here is my solution:

```
%binary tree generator
bintree(0,[]). %0 nodes - empty list
bintree(1,[[],[]]). %1 node - list containing 2 empty lists
bintree(N,[Cl,Cr]) :-
    N>=2, %check only if at least 2 nodes
    between(0,N,Nl), %let Nl be in [0,N]
    between(0,N,Nr), %similarly for Nr
    Ns is Nl+Nr+1, %total no. of nodes should add up correctly
    N==Ns, %so check for that
    bintree(Nl,Cl), %children should also be valid binary trees
    bintree(Nr,Cr).
```

Comment: That's a very bad "generator". For example, try the most general query: `?- bintree(N, Tree).` It yields two solutions, and then says: `ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. I highly recommend you use CLP(FD) **constraints** to reason over integers, as in lurker's program. This will make your solution more general, usable in all directions as we expect from a relation. In your solution, both the wording ("check") and behaviour are very *imperative*, and your code only works in a very limited set of usage modes. As another example, try `?- bintree(N, [_,_]).`, and compare them!