# Dividing two integers with an alternative way

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

Let's consider that n=s(s(...s(0)...)) (simply n= s^n(0)). How could write a program calculating the division of two integers? I mean s^(n//m) (thats the definition of the division) . Any ideas? For example, if we had the question:

```
?-divide(s(s(s(s(0)))),s(0),D).
```

i have written the following code:

```
 nat(0).
 nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
 divide(0,_,D) :- D is 0.
 divide(s(X),s(Y),D) :- divide(X,Y,D).
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by division? You might use multiplication, see above tag!

Comment: i mean that i want to execute the division of 4 and 1, to give me 4. @false

Comment: That's not the interesting case. What about `divide(s(s(s(s(0)))), s(s(0)),D)`?

Comment: s(s(s(s(0))) is 4. and the other is 2. so , i want to take D=2.

Comment: Start with [`prod/3`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139640/prolog-successor-notation-yields-incomplete-result-and-infinite-loop/10141181#10141181)

Comment: i mean whats the problem with this i have written: nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
divide(0,_,D) :- D is 0.
divide(s(X),s(Y),D) :- divide(X,Y,D).

Comment: `(is)/2` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: i dont understand you. sorry:) did you see my code?

Comment: with `divide(s(X),s(Y),D) :- divide(X,Y,D)` you are saying that `X/Y=D -> (X+1)/(Y+1)=D`, which is wrong (in classical mathematics)

Comment: You usually don't build division from scratch. You build it at least from addition and subtraction. Where is addition and subtraction in your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30016859/992406

Answer (score 1):

Your predicate `divide/3` assumes wrongly that the following equation holds when x and y are numbers: 
  **(x-1)/(y-1) = x/y**
A counter-example is:  **(16-1)/(4-1) = 5** is different from **16/4 = 4**

It seems you are trying to base your predicate on the well-know addition predicate:

```
add(0,Y,Y).
add(s(X),Y,s(Z)) :- add(X,Y,Z).
```

but division is a multiplicative not an additive operation. A possible way of solving your problem is to think of division as an iterated subtraction (as multiplication is an iterated addition). As your predicate is on natural numbers it must implement integral division as you wrote in the question.

Comment: i tried something like this but i dont take right results @migfilg nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
divide(0,_,0).
divide(X,Y,D) :- X@<Y, D is 0.
divide(X,s(0),X).
divide(_,0,undefined) :- !.
divide(X,Y,D) :- A is 1, divide2(s(X),s(Y),A,D1), D is D1.

divide2(X,Y,A,D1) :- A*X@>=Y, D1 is A.
divide2(X,Y,A,D1) :- A*X@<Y, A1 is A+1, divide2(X,Y,A1,D2) , D1 is D2.

Comment: You should not use `is/2` for unification: use `=/2` or just replace variables by the terms they should be unified with (for instance `D` by `0` in your 2nd clause). You need cuts in almost all clauses. What do you mean by `AX` in `divide2/4`? Is it  `A` times `X`? As it stands it is a free variable. Your last clause of `divide/3` calls `divide2` with `s(X)` and `s(Y)`, why? Write in a paper the steps of the division *16/4* using repeated subtractions and try to see how a program could do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
s(0).
s(X):- X.

plus(0, Y, Y).
plus(s(X), Y, s(Z)):- plus(X , Y , Z).

minus(A, B, C) :- plus(C, B, A).

divide(_, 0, 0).
divide(0, _ , 0).
divide(X, s(0), X).
divide(A, B, s(N)) :- minus(A, B, R), divide(R, B, N).
```

Example:

```
| ?- divide(s(s(s(0))), s(0), N).

N = s(s(s(0))) ?

yes
| ?- divide(s(s(s(s(0)))), s(s(0)), N).

N = s(s(0)) ?

yes
```

This solution obviously only works for perfect divisions like 4/2 or 6/3 etc. Since we can only represent natural numbers using Peano's numerals.

Answer (score 0):

Old post,but i have a same assignment.So the answer is:

```
%nat:Is X natural?,nat2:Is X,Y naturals?
nat(0).
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
nat2(0,s(Y)) :- nat(Y).
nat2(s(X),s(Y)) :- nat2(X,Y). 

%Summary of X+Y=Z
sum(X,0,X) :- nat(X).
sum(X,s(Y),s(Z)) :- sum(X,Y,Z).

%Minus of X-Y=Z is same as Y+Z=X
minus(X,Y,Z) :- sum(Y,Z,X). 

%Multiplication of X*Y,add X+0(Z) Y times(recursive)
mult(X,0,0).
mult(X,s(Y),D):-mult(X,Y,Z), sum(X,Z,D).

%Divide,check special occasions,add to W the s(0)(1) recursive.
divide(X,Y,D) :- div(X,Y,D,_).
div(s(X),0,undefined,_).
div(0,s(Y),0,_).
div(0,0,undefined,_).
div(X,Y,0,X) :- X \== 0,Y \== 0,nat2(X,Y).
div(X,Y,D,L) :- X \== 0,Y \== 0,minus(X,Y,Z),div(Z,Y,W,L),sum(W,s(0),D).
```