# Division using Peano numbers

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I am trying to make a program that divides two Peano numbers. Unfortunately, the cycle starts running after I look for other answers. Is there any way to avoid duplicates using my method?

```
    s(0).
    s(X):- X.

    plus(0,Y,Y).
    plus(s(X), Y, s(Z)):- plus(X,Y,Z).

    minus(A, B, C) :- plus(C, B, A).

    division(0, _ , 0).
    division(X, s(0), X).
    division(A, B, s(N)) :- minus(A, B, R), division(R, B, N).
```

Output

```
?- division(s(s(s(s(0)))), s(0),X).
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
false.
```

Output#2

```
?- divide(s(s(s(s(0)))), Y,X).
Y = s(0),
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
Y = s(s(s(s(0)))),
X = s(0) ;
Y = X, X = s(s(0)) ;
Y = s(0),
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
Y = s(0),
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
Y = s(0),
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
Y = s(0),
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
Y = s(0),
X = s(s(s(s(0)))) ;
;ERROR: Out of local stack
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10139640/772868)

Comment: I think your rule `s(X) :- X.` is a bit flawed. For example, `s(division(0, _ , 0)).` would be then true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Correctness.** First, let's consider correctness issues. According to your definition, 0/0 = 0. That is, `division(0, 0, 0)`. So you are stating that dividing 0 by 0 is 0.  Another issue is the definition of `s/1`. See [successor-arithmetics](/questions/tagged/successor-arithmetics) for more.

**Redundant answers.** To identify sources of redundancy, consider the clauses of each predicate.  Is it possible that they both apply for the same ground query? Let's see: For `plus/3` this cannot happen because the fact needs `0` in the first argument, but the rule needs `s(_)`. This can never happen at the same time.  Thus there is no source of redundancy.  For `division/3` however, both apply for `division(0, s(0), 0).` Further the second fact and the rule may apply both too.

**Non-termination.** Before going into the technical details discussed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10141181/772868), let's first take a step back about what you are expecting that you get from 4/X = Y.  Evidently, these solutions `(X,Y): [(1,4),(2,2),(4,1)]`. But what about a solution with `0`?